# Python MySQL Connector Timeout

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Inserting records into a MySQL database using Python MySQL Connector. Process works around 98% of the time. I am getting intermittent timeout responses from the server. Other times the script just hangs and nothing happens, which is the worse possible situation.

Can I timeout/kill the process using threading?

Can I set a timeout on the execute or commit statement?

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="...", user="...", password="...", database="...")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#Seems to always work up to this point

sql = "INSERT INTO test (name,tagline,location,experience) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test')

try:
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()

except Exception as e:
        print(e)
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: How is your _server_ configured?

Comment: I am not sure. It is a Linux server. Perhaps I can make some changes?

Comment: If you are using mysql.connector.connect to connect with DB you can simply use connection_timeout parameter to define a timeout externally make sure value given will be in seconds

Comment: OK, but when I add connection_timeout=1 and the connection does in fact timeout, I get no exception. It incorrectly prints "record inserted". How can I catch the timeout event?